# Moving back programmatically in table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4

I have one tab bar app. In a specific tab, I use a table view for configuration stuff.
When I click on an item in the table view, I go to the next view (the view of the selected item).
In this second view, I have a validation button, and I need to go back to the previous view when clicking on this button, how this could be achieved ?
I try the [self.view removeFromSuperView] but it just "delete" the current view.

Can somebody help ?
Thanks a lot,
Luc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such scenario usually navigation controller is used. In that case you will be able to pushViewController/popViewController. If you don't want to use navigation controller, you should add old view controllers view to superview.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot. I do use a navigation controller, but I did not really use pop and push methods. Thanks a lot, that really helps.